# Regex for date in format DD/MMM/YYYY:HH24:mm:ss

Tags: regex, string, datetime

I have a date time stamp as follows

```
10/Jun/1998:16:21:03 +0000
```

I need to break down the date portion and the time portion
i have used 
`^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)/\d{4}$`
to get the date broken up.

How can i write a regex to get the time separated: as HH , MM , SS

Thank you in advance ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\b` will work for you.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/6W9cL1/3)

Explanation :

`(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])` --> Match 00 to 19 or 20,21,22,23

`[0-5][0-9]` --> Match 00 to 59

PS : You need to use *word boundary* i.e `\b` to ensure that the "time part" of your String is matched correctly.

Comment: also if i want to extract the entire 16:21:03 segment along with the broken down format, how can i do that? The output i want will be 16:21:03 , 16 , 21 , 03

Comment: @Dee - Which language are you using?

Comment: @Dee - Try https://regex101.com/r/58l1gF/1. group 1 --> hour, group 2--> minutes, group 3 --> seconds

Comment: ♦ I am wrting a regex to get data for a hive table. In your second link, yes it gives the parts of the time. Is there a way to get the full match along with that as well? then i can have the whole time, and hh mm ss broken down as well

Comment: Hi again I got it [link](https://regex101.com/r/58l1gF/2) Grpup 1 gives the whole date :) Thanks a lot for the tips! (y)